# sqlite on iOS 4.3.x much slower than 4.2.1

Tags: iphone, sqlite, ios-4.2, ios4

Why is sqlite on iOS 4.3.x much slower than 4.2.1. The same sqlite query (select query with 3 joins) gives the results much faster on 4.2.1 than 4.3.x.

Is there any particular reason for the same? Or is it a bug on Apple's side?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it on a device or simulator? I've had some sqlite issues on the simulator that weren't causing trouble on a device.

Comment: The issue is on the device. I have tested it on multiple devices.

Comment: Could there be a bottleneck elsewhere?  When you run the Time Profiler instrument against your application, what dominates the sample times?  If it is indeed SQLite, you may wish to file a bug report for the regression: https://bugreport.apple.com .

Comment: Is the sqlite version the same? How are you benchmarking this? How much faster/slower is it?

Answer (score 0):

Is it the same database file?  You may want to compact the database again.  I'm not an iphone developer, but if they changed the filesystem from 4.2.x to 4.3.x there may be some issues with accessing trees from an old file.  sqlite provides queries (look up `VACUUM` in the docs) that will compact and clean the database.  As a last resort you can also try rebuilding the entire database (i.e. SELECT * from [each table in turn]; INSERT [each row] INTO [newdb].[table])

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, it's the same database file. I have tried installing the app afresh but with no positive results.

Comment: Tried your approach of recreating the database and compacting it. But didn't make any difference.